# AntD Upload in Form with React using valuePropName & getValueFromEvent - How to Overwrite and Upload Only One File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state, antd

I am trying to incorporate AntD [Upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/) & [Form](https://ant.design/components/form/) with React using [Upload Manually](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-upload-manually) & [Other Form Controls](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-other) sample codes.

I thought by using `setFileList([file])` instead of `setFileList([...fileList, file])` the new file being uploaded would overwrite the existing file, but I end up with both files in an array when I submit the form.

```
const uploadProps = {
  beforeUpload: (file) => {
    //********** Original sample code **********//
    // setFileList([...fileList, file]);
    //*********** Changed to only get a single file **********//
    setFileList([file]);
    return false;
  },
  fileList: fileList,
};
```

However, when I change `valuePropName` in `Form.Item` to some other variable, I get the desired result (array of one with the only the new file information) when I submit the form .

```
<Form.Item
  name='upload'
  //********** Returns multiple files in an array **********//
  // valuePropName='fileList'
  //********** Returns a single file in an array **********//
  // valuePropName='somethingElse'
  getValueFromEvent={normFile}
>
  <Upload {...uploadProps}>
    <Button>Select File</Button>
  </Upload>
</Form.Item>
```

Is `valuePropName` conflicting with `getValueFromEvent`? I tried following the variables but I'm at a loss. Could someone please explain how this works? Full code snippet is below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Upload, Button } from 'antd';

const FileUploadPage = () => {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      fileList,
    });
  }, [form, fileList]);

  const submitHandler = async (info) => {
    // Submit action
    console.log(info);
  };

  const uploadProps = {
    onRemove: (file) => {
      const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
      const newFileList = fileList.slice();
      newFileList.splice(index, 1);
      setFileList(newFileList);
    },
    beforeUpload: (file) => {
      //********** Original sample code **********//
      // setFileList([...fileList, file]);
      //********** Changed to only get a single file **********//
      setFileList([file]);

      return false;
    },
    fileList: fileList,
  };

  const normFile = (e) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
      <h1>Upload Form</h1>

      <Form onFinish={submitHandler} form={form}>
        <Form.Item name='upload' valuePropName='fileList' getValueFromEvent={normFile}>
          <Upload {...uploadProps}>
            <Button>Select File</Button>
          </Upload>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
            Upload
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUploadPage;
```

Comment: [Description](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem) of valuePropName says: This prop is an encapsulation of getValueProps, which will be invalid after customizing getValueProps. So yes, they are conflicting